# Deleting a Node at a given position in a Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to delete a Node at a given index but I keep failing tests and sometimes even get a `NullPointerException`. Here is what I have done so far:

```
public void remove(int pos)

{

 if (head == last)

        {
            head = null;
            last = null;
        }
        if (pos == size - 1)

            return removeLast();

        if (pos == 0)

            return removeFirst();

        else
        {
            DoubleListNode<E> current = head;

            for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i ++)

            {

                current = current.getNext();

            }
            current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());

            current.getNext().getNext().setPrev(current);

            return current.getData();
        }
}
```

Comment: You are not checking if getNext() returns null. Imagine what would happen if your linked list had only one element (getNext would return a null pointer).

Comment: if that were the case wouldn't it go to if (pos == 0) as if there is only one node then the position would be 0 right?

Comment: pos can be whatever number you pass to remove(). It can be bigger than the length of the list, and that would mean that the for loop would go beyond the last element.

Comment: I did put a precondition that the pos would be >= 0 and <= size. It still gives me the error and also fails test cases. I think my logic isnt right here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to delete from doubly linkedlist:

Let the node to be deleted is del.

1. If node to be deleted is head node, then change the head pointer to
   next current head.
2. Set next of previous to del, if previous to del exists.
3. Set prev of next to del, if next to del exists.

Remember, here you have to maintain both the previous and next pointer 
as-well handle the null condition from both side.